# Android Update TextView outside Grid in Intent without reloading

Tags: android, gridview, textview, field

See [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkqwh.jpg)

I'd like to update a TextField (TextView) when I press a button in a GridView. I'd like to do this without reloading the intent itself. Does someone have some idea's?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: (Main intent) http://codeshare.io/ahy5Y

Comment: (Grid intent) http://codeshare.io/uQxC2 view line 453 - 458.

Comment: Yes well in first case I just want to know how I can pass values to adapter's constructor? Next step will be dynamic values.

Comment: You should add the relevant code to the question instead of linking the complete classes in the comments. See [http://sscce.org/](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank Stefan for you help, I will add some smaller code later tonight on it. Maybe it will clarify a little bit more. I hoped someone just had the answer when I posted the image. But it seems not.